# Are there any plants that parasitize on animals?

Tags: botany, parasitology, parasitism

It seems, fungi often infect animals, while plants it seems, never. Is it because the cellulose cell walls make them incompatible with animal tissue?

Comment: The question in the title differs from the one in the post. Can you please pick one of the two questions only?

Comment: The threshold between parasite and predator is somewhat blurry. Would carnivorous plants be a good example? The only true good example coming to my mind are plants that get insects to carry their pollen but don't give them any nectar as reward. There are also plants that lure insects in but imitating a potential mate and then just use these insects for pollen transportation again. Are these good examples or did you mean endo-parasites only?

Comment: Why would they? They evolved to become phototropic.Although carnivorous and protocarnivorous plants exist for survival advantages.Can you be a bit more specific so that it's easy to relate?

Comment: Boundaries between parasite and symbiotic are also fuzzy. What about the algae that are symbiotic with sloths? [Molecular evidence for a diverse green algal community growing in the hair of sloths and a specific association with Trichophilus welckeri(Chlorophyta, Ulvophyceae)](https://bmcevolbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2148-10-86)

Comment: Well...there is the Venus Fly Trap.

Comment: I am voting to close as unclear as long as the OP has not address the difficulties of definitions of ecological interactions and has not addresses whether the presented examples would answer the question or not.

Comment: + Helicosporidium https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pgen.1004355

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

Acrochaetium spiculiphilum is an marine endozoic parasite on sponges.

It is a Biliphyte algae and thus a plant.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-the-marine-biological-association-of-the-united-kingdom/article/abs/observations-on-an-endozoic-red-alga/A2486145D3811B18BCC65A81B24ADA56

Answer (score -2):

Yes! Here's a paper published August 2018
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982218308157

Comment: No, ans the abstract says, the parasitic plant attacks the insect-induced tumors of the other plants. In other words, plant tissue.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not acceptable on Stack Exchange sites. The link may change or become unreachable in the future, and without a summary of what the link contains this answer would be useless. Please summarize what is in the link (**don't** just copy and paste) and use the link solely for reference. If you remove the link and the answer cannot stand on its own, it is not a good answer.

Comment: Could you please summarise the relevant content of that paper? Posts should be self-contained and not rely on a link only, because the link might get broken.